US Citizen living in Switzerland with permanent residency, and married to an EU citizen. Can I work in the EU without living there?
I am an American living in Switzerland with permanent residency, and married to an EU citizen.  Being married to an EU citizen should give me the ability to live and/or work in the EU.  But can I work in the EU (without living there), while living in Switzerland?  Or do I have to live in the EU to apply for jobs there?

Are you asking whether you can work in Switzerland for a EU employer?


Being married to an EU citizen should give me the ability to live and/or work in the EU.

That's not quite the case, the logic of the system is that your spouse has the right to live and work anywhere in the EU and you have the right to go with them. To gain the right to work in an EU country on that basis, it is therefore essential that your spouse is already exercising their EU freedom of movement rights in that specific country. In practice, it's difficult to see many scenarios where you don't live in that country but where you yourself reside is not even the most pressing issue, your spouse's status is.
On the other hand, if you do not reside and work in a country (i.e. you're not physically present there when you're carrying out the work) then you don't need to worry about immigration rules or your rights as the spouse of an EU citizen. You would be working in Switzerland, you are (presumably) allowed to work in Switzerland already, and that's all there is to it. You would not be working in the EU.
Instead, the real problem is finding a way for your prospective employer to extend a contract across borders without breaking labor laws, tax laws, and social security / mandatory insurance rules and without breaking every assumption behind their payroll process. That's an entirely separate issue and would still be a problem if you were yourself a Swiss citizen or a citizen of the country where your employer is located.
In practice, there are various solutions like being employed by the Swiss branch of your employer, using a third party to hire you, or setting yourself up as a self-employed / freelance person but they all require a little bit of work and additional overhead. On the employer side, there are businesses that can take care of this, usually calling their services something like “global employer of record”, “professional employer organization”, “global payroll”, or “HR outsourcing”.

What about cross-border worker arrangements, where the employee actually commutes across the border?  I realize that it's more common to go the other way, but it should be possible in both directions, shouldn't it?  (Assuming the residence in Switzerland is close enough to the border, of course.)

@phoog I don't think it would be as easy for a third-country citizen as it is for an EU citizen but I carefully avoided the topic because I don't really know and I didn't think that it was what the OP had in mind.
